# how can test my API in different PC which is in same wifi network using my IPv4 address?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

how can I test my API in different PC which is in same WIFI network using my IPv4 address ?
like if i have if 192.168.2.222 then I got the error [URL image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pxm4G.jpg) plz tell me how can I solve.The API is working fine in local host. but in IPv4 I got this error so plz guide me. I have tried all the configuration from different sources but still getting this error.

Comment: Please make sure that the PC that is hosting the website actually allows access from your local network and isn't just restricted to your local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

serve the application on your host IP address

**command**

```
php artisan serve --host=192.168.2.222
```

Now you can access the app on another computer on the same network using the ip address

If connection to the app is frozen, try and check your firewall settings.

But on default, this command should do the magic without any extra steps.

Comment: okay thank you for the help it's working !

Comment: You're welcome. If this answered your question. You can mark it as answered and upvote it. Thanks .

Answer (score 0):

you can do some like this

192.168.31.91/your_project_name/public/api/Your_API_Route

if your project doesn't have public then just

192.168.31.91/your_project_name/api/Your_API_Route

and also check your firewall if it allows

Answer (score 0):

Use ifconfig to find out your local network ip

In my case it is 192.168.1.131:

ifconfig
en0: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
options=400<CHANNEL_IO>
inet 192.168.1.131 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
media: autoselect
status: active

Then you need to run the server with

php -S 0.0.0.0:5500 index.php or

php -S 192.168.1.131:5500 index.php

You can now open a browser on a device on your local network with

http://192.168.1.131:5500